# Getting index out of bounds error when using % operator

Tags: java

I am having trouble with a method for an assignment, so basically when I use this method

```
public class DFS {

private int[][] a;

public DFS(int[][] a){
    this.a=a;
}
/**
 * Recursively visits all vertices in matrix
 * @param x
 * @param y
 */
public void search(int x, int y){
    if(a[x][y] == -1){
        return;
    }
    else{
        a[x][y] = -1;
        System.out.println((char)(x+65)+", "+(char)(y+65));
        if(x<a.length-1){
            if(a[x+1][y] == 1){
                search(x+1, y);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(a[(x+1)%a.length][y] == 1){
                search((x+1)%a.length, y);
            }
        }
        if(y<a.length-1){
            if(a[x][y+1] == 1){
                search(x, y+1);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(a[x][(y+1)%a.length] == 1){
                search(x, (y+1)%a.length);
            }
        }
        if(x>0){
            if(a[x-1][y] == 1){
                search(x-1, y);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(a[(x-1)%a.length][y] == 1){
                search((x-1)%a.length, y);
            }
        }
        if(y>0){
            if(a[x][y-1] == 1){
                search(x, y-1);
            }
        }
        else{
            if(a[x][(y-1)%a.length] == 1){
                search(x, (y-1)%a.length);
            }
        }

    }
}
```

}

I keep getting an `ArrayIndexOutOfBounds` error, but how is this possible if I'm using modulus with n as the size of the array? Here is the full class file.

Comment: There are many cases where you are not using the modulus. There is not enough here to fully diagnose your problem. What line is the exception being thrown on?

Comment: On line 50, 31 and 56 but I don't need modulus on the variables not being incremented right? How can they go out of bounds if they don't increment

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and tell us which lines are causing the error.  Don't just give the line number but tell us which line are those line numbers. Also, please tell us the size of the array and what values are being passed in during the error. Finally, I'd recommend using a debugger for code like this

Comment: I don't know how to post the full stack trace but I added comments for now. The size of the array I'm using is is 5 and the initial values being passed in are (4, 0)

Comment: How is the array initialized?

Comment: It's initialized in the main class by using the n value the user inputs, which in my case is 5, and then the array is passed into a separate class which this method belongs to

Comment: It's possible because you're mistaken about something.  `n` may not be the size of the array, you may be getting the error on a different statement where you don't use `%`, etc.  Don't ASSUME -- use a debugger or println statements to verify you have the values you think you do.

Comment: It shouldn't be that hard to provide a more complete code sample. The only two unknowns at this point are `n` and `a` and your unwillingness to provide them leaves everybody here guessing. Please provide a [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I call your class as follows:

```
new DFS(new int[5][5], 5).search(0, 4);
```

I get a negative x index on this line:

```
if (a[(x - 1) % a.length][y] == 1)
```

The result of `(0 - 1) % 5` is `-1`, hence the `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. In Java the sign of the result of a modulo operation is determined by the sign of the dividend.

Comment: I thought -1 % 5 would be 4, but yeah that's whats's going wrong. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Demo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][]=new int[5][6];
        System.out.println(a.length);
    }
}
```

Here a.length will give you 5.

but in your code you go full derp trying

```
if(y<a.length-1){
    if(a[x][y+1] == 1){
```

see here you're comparing the line numbers with y which you use as your column number.

lets try a drawing

| _ | _ | _ |

| _ | _ | _ |

| _ | _ | _ |

| _ | _ | _ |

| _ | _ | _ |

| _ | _ | _ |

Here we have 6 lines and 3 columns
so if you try y<(6-1) and your y is 4
then if you try to access the fourth column, you'll get a ArrayOutOfBounds Exception.

Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: The matrix is initialized in another class as a square array, specifically like this int[][] adjMatrix = new int[n][n];

Comment: ArrayOutOfBounds meens you're trying to access a spot outside of the array, so if you have a 4 by 4 square at some point you're trying to access a spot in your square with x >= 4 or y >= 4 or x<0 or y<0